# How to call an API in Nodejs with post method?

Tags: node.js

I have a code sample in PHP in curling API. How to curl this in Nodejs?

```
<?php
$apiKey = "Your API Key Goes Here";
$payUrl = "https://example.com/api/requery/";
$data['apiKey'] = $apiKey;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $payUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
$r = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($r);
?>
```

Comment: Put this flow in postman and you can get this in any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) package thats included in node to send your request to the API

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  hostname: 'encrypted.google.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET'
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
req.end();
```